# How can i work on array in React with ".map" methos?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, algorithm

I've been trying for a couple of days to fix this problem but I really can't seem to figure it out.

I am trying to develop a Blog in React, I have created a 'Data.jsx' file which contains all the information of each post.
A thing like that:

```
import POST from '../../assets/blog-post.jpg'

const Data = [

{
  id: 1,
  image: POST,
  title: 'This is my first post!',
  github: 'https://github.com',
  read: '/Blog/buymeanr6please'
},
{
  id: 2,
  image: POST,
  title: '2',
  github: 'https://github.com',
  read: 'https://gitlba.com'
},
{
  id: 3,
  image: POST,
  title: '3',
  github: 'https://github.com',
  read: 'https://gitlba.com'
},
{
  id: 4,
  image: POST,
  title: '4',
  github: 'https://github.com',
  read: 'https://gitlba.com'
},
{
  id: 5,
  image: POST,
  title: '5',
  github: 'https://github.com',
  read: 'https://gitlba.com'
},
{
  id: 6,
  image: POST,
  title: '6',
  github: 'https://github.com',
  read: 'https://gitlba.com'
}

]

 export default Data
```

Now, I want to create a preview of the last 3 posts (so of 4, 5, 6) but I can't work with the array in the other file.
All 6 posts are shown.

```
import React from 'react'
import './blogPreview.css'
import Data from '../blog/Data'
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'

const BlogPreview = () => {

let navigate = useNavigate()

return (
<section id='blogPreview'>

 <h5>My Recent Post</h5>
 <h6 onClick={() => {navigate("/Blog")}}>(yea i also have a blog, check it out!)</h6>
 <h2>Blog</h2>

 <div className="container blogPreview__container">

  {

    Data.map(({id, image, title, github, read}) => {

        return(

          <article key={id} className='blogPreview__item'>

            <div className="blogPreview__item-image">
            
              <img src={image} alt={title} />
              
            </div>

            <h3>{title}</h3>

            <div className="blogPreview__item-cta">

              <a href={read} className='btn btn-primary'>Read</a>
              <a href={github} className='btn' target='_blank'>Github</a>

            </div>

          </article>

        )

    })

  }

 </div>

</section>
)
}

export default BlogPreview
```

I know it might be a bit confusing, I hope I explained myself well, if it helps this is [link](https://github.com/Ho3pLi/my-place) of the updated repo.

Comment: Does this really have anything to do with React or with your specific data, or are you just asking [how to get the last 3 elements of an array in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)?

Comment: If you want to return only 3 objects from the Data array, you can use **.slice(0,3)** 0 being the start, and 3 as the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Data.slice(3).map()`

This will start ignoring the first three elements of the array

Answer (score 0):

If the raw data is not structured then sort that data by `id` or any other appropiate field first then apply slice to extract elements.

To sort in descending order by id

```
data = data.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(b.id) - parseFloat(a.id));
```

then take first 3 objects from data array

```
data = data.slice(0, 3);
```

If your data is strcutured and you are sure the latest elements comes always at end, then use `slice(-n)` to extract last n objects.

```
data = data.slice(-3);
```